# Importing database error CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I import my database to my host (phpMyAdmin) I get this error message

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  `database name` 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Error
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `connorma_database`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS  `connorma_database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses_coIKrnWBYz'@'localhost' to database 'connorma_database'

Comment: please check your database username and password - Generally is error comes when some password is set for the respactive database

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the user `cpses_coIKrnWBYz'@'localhost` doesn't have access to the database `connorma_database` this may happen because you make the database from the root account and then you try to import the database with the logging of the user `cpses_coIKrnWBYz'@'localhost` to solve this use following steps

- Log in to `phpmyadimn` as the `root` user
- select the databse `connorma_database`
- go to the `privileges` tab
- add the user `cpses_coIKrnWBYz'@'localhost` with necessary privileges

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while exporting & importing my database. This is how i solved my error.

```
 - Selected custom method while exporting database
 - In File name template option, I gave the same name as my database name(where i wanted to import)
 - Checked this checkbox - Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement
 - Go
```

That's it. This error was coming because I was exporting the database by the old database name and importing to new database where the database name might not have the same name.